# Plot ratio of geom_bar on second y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the ratio of geom_bar using a plot_line on a second axis. 
Here is my dataframe :

```
df <- data.frame(code=c('F6', 'F6','D4', 'D4', 'F5', 'F5', 'C4', 'C4', 'F7', 'F7'),
           group=c('0','1','0','1','0','1','0','1','0','1'),
           count=c(80, 700, 30, 680, 100, 360, 70, 230, 40, 200))
```

For the moment, I plot the following figure :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=code, y=count, fill=group)) +
  geom_bar(stat ="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]

And I would like to have also the ratio between groups.
For example, for C4 it would be 70/230*100=30%. Here is what it could represent:

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: Hey @Kamloops! Are you saying that you want to produce the second graph in your question using code? It's not clear if you made the second graph with code or with photo editing software.

Comment: Hi @Nova , yes of course, I would like do to it using R and ggplot. I just did it quickly with a photo editing software here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the `tidyverse` library to calculate the percentage for each group, then adding that to your plot using a secondary axis:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(code=c('F6', 'F6','D4', 'D4', 'F5', 'F5', 'C4', 'C4', 'F7', 'F7'),
                 group=c('0','1','0','1','0','1','0','1','0','1'),
                 count=c(80, 700, 30, 680, 100, 360, 70, 230, 40, 200))
```

Now, make another data frame that calculates the percentage as you directed. I used `spread` to do this. Also, I calculated the percentage as 7 TIMES the percentage calculated, because you want to put the percentage (which goes from 0-100) on the same graph which goes from 0-700 counts. So 7*100 will fill the entire graph. I also added a new field called "order" because geom_line doesn't like using a factor (group) to connect a line.

```
  percentage.df <- df %>% 
      spread(group, count) %>% 
      mutate(percentage = 7*(`0`/`1`)*100) %>% 
      mutate(order = c(1:nrow(.)))
```

Now, when you plot this, you can specify a secondary axis, but you have to remember to tell ggplot that you should divide the numbers by 7 for the secondary axis labels to make sense.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=code, y=count)) +
  geom_bar(stat ="identity", position="dodge", aes(fill=group)) +
  geom_point(data = percentage.df, aes(code, percentage)) +
  geom_line(data = percentage.df, aes(order, percentage)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . /7))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try to normalise the ratios to the maximum y-value (`count`).

```
library(tidyverse)
MAX= max(df$count)

df %>% 
  group_by(code) %>% 
  mutate(ratio = count[1]/count[2]) %>%
  mutate(ratio_norm = MAX*ratio) %>%   
 ggplot(aes(x=code)) +
  geom_col(aes(y=count, fill=group), position="dodge") + 
  geom_point(data = . %>% distinct(code, ratio_norm), aes(y=ratio_norm)) +
  geom_line(data = . %>% distinct(code,  ratio_norm), aes(y=ratio_norm, group = 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./MAX, labels = scales::percent))
```

[image]

Comment: ahh, you did what I was too lazy to do :P